# QgsLayerTreeNode ignores expansion calls

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a Python plugin for QGIS. My goal is to add a layer group and then add a vector layer to it. The group is collapsed by default, and I'd like to expand it. But the setExpanded() method does not seem to have any effect until I expand the group via the GUI. Here's my code:

```
self.layer_group = self.layer_tree_root.insertGroup(0, self.plugin_name)
# To be added to group, layer has to be added to project first
self.project.addMapLayer(layer, addToLegend=False)  # layer is defined elsewhere in the code
# Explcitly add layer at position 0 or else it adds it to bottom
self.layer_group.insertLayer(0, layer)
self.layer_group.setExpanded(True)
```

The group stays collapsed. Printing `self.layer_group.isExpanded()` outputs `True` before and after calling `self.layer_group.setExpanded(True)`. If I monitor the state change by connecting the `self.layer_group.expandedChanged` signal to a printing function, it doesn't print anything, so I conclude `setExpanded()` calls are ignored.
But if I expand the group via a click in the GUI, and then call `setExpanded()` from the console, it all starts working fine.

Why are calls to `setExpanded()` ignored and what 'unmutes' them after I expand the group in the GUI?

Comment: Seems the same issue (but opposite): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420255/how-to-collapse-legend-in-toc-via-pyqgis The solution- call `setExpanded(False)` first?

Comment: Thank you, PolyGeo, it works! Looks like a bug though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, you have to call `setExpanded(False)` first (seems like a bug). Then it works fine. More details here:

[How to collapse legend in ToC via PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420255/how-to-collapse-legend-in-toc-via-pyqgis)