# Collapsing legend in ToC via PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, table-of-contents

I am creating QGIS simple plugin which adds and set styles. It works like a charm, however i want to collapse all legends(categories) from styles in given layer i tried

```
            layer.setAutoRefreshEnabled(True)
            layerNode = self.root.findLayer(layer.id())
            layerNode.setExpanded(False)
```

but it seems to take no effect. As you can see in code snippet i am loading one layer after another so i decided to use this method in *forloop* to collapse every loaded layer but it does nothing. In `layerNode` is stored `QgsLayerTreeLayer` but `setExpanded()` takes no effect nor error. What is the trick? I found a solution  in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329130/is-there-a-way-to-hide-range-categories-using-python-code-on-a-vector-layer) thread, but i though that passing `setExpanded` directly in *forloop* would be better than creating another method.

```
def add_lidar(self,pos):
    if AutoProjekt.get_lidar_dir.has_been_called:
        selected = [item.text() for item in self.dlg.lidarList.selectedItems()]
        if len(selected) > 0:
            # ProgressBar
            self.dialog, self.bar = self.progdialog(0)
            self.bar.setValue(0)
            self.bar.setMaximum(100)
            fb = QgsProcessingFeedback()
            fb.progressChanged.connect(self.progress_changed)
            QApplication.processEvents()

            shapeGroup = self.root.insertGroup(pos,'LIDAR')
            selected.sort()
            count = len(selected)
            for i,filename in enumerate(selected):
                progValue = i+1
                splitted = filename.split(sep=' dirs:')
                name = splitted[0].lower()
                path = splitted[1]
                #if name in self.LIDAR:
                layer = QgsVectorLayer(path,name)
                
                if self.dlg.styleCheckBox.isChecked() and name in self.LIDAR:
                    self.set_style(layer, self.POLYGON, self.style['LIDAR'], name)
                    self.set_style(layer, self.POINT, self.style['LIDAR'], name)
                    self.set_style(layer, self.LINE, self.style['LIDAR'], name)

                QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
                shapeGroup.insertChildNode(1,QgsLayerTreeLayer(layer))

                layer.setAutoRefreshEnabled(True)
                layerNode = self.root.findLayer(layer.id())
                layerNode.setExpanded(False)

                progress = progValue / float(count) * 100  
                self.bar.setValue(progress)  
                QApplication.processEvents() 

            time.sleep(0.5)  
            self.dialog.close()  
            self.bar.setValue(0)
```

I have found that layer has status isExpanded = False even in ToC it appears to be expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution, but it looks silly.
Layer after added has `isExpanded` value set to `False` even though in ToC appears to be expanded.
By setting status of node to `True` then to `False` it takes effect in ToC:

```
layerNode = self.root.findLayer(layer.id())
layerNode.setExpanded(True)#added TRUE
layerNode.setExpanded(False)
```

I do not know why it happens that way. I thought that `layer.setAutoRefreshEnabled(True)` would solve everything.

Comment: Thank you for this fix. Works also for the opposite case.